# JButton Set Action

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm testing to see if the user had entered something. If they didn't if JFrame will display the following field they failed to populate. I don't know what I should do, I cant get it to work. Is there something else I can use instead?

It will test for these after the user hit the JButton to continue

```
register.setText(e->{
        if(pin.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Pin");
        }else if(birth_year.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Birth Year");
        }else if(password.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Password");
        }else if(name.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Name");
        }else if(alias.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Alias");
        }else if(gender.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Gender");
        }else if(astro_sign.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Astro Sign");
        }else if(dep.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Enter Deposit Amount");
        }else if(pin.equals("") 
                && birth_year.equals("") 
                && password.equals("") 
                && name.equals("") 
                && alias.equals("")
                && gender.equals("")
                && astro_sign.equals("")
                && dep.equals("")){
            l_message.setForeground(Color.red);
            l_message.setText("Please Fill In The Fields");
        }else if(!pin.equals("") 
                && !birth_year.equals("") 
                && !password.equals("") 
                && !name.equals("") 
                && !alias.equals("")
                && !gender.equals("")
                && !astro_sign.equals("")
                && !dep.equals("")){

            l_message.setForeground(Color.green);
            l_message.setText("Successful Registration");
                                }
                        }
                );
```

I keep getting the syntax error of incompatible types: String is not a functional interface on the setText

Comment: [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)? I'm also curious as to what you expected by using `setText` over say, `addActionListener`

Comment: Just updated it sorry it would test after the user hit the JButton to continue

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) or [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: I'm setting text within a set bounds on a jframe that will update the color and what the text says depending on the users input.

Comment: But, that's not how buttons work

Comment: How would you suggest I do it I originally had a JOptionPane to display the failed area

Comment: @DRodriguez what is this register? is it your JLabel or Text Field where you show the error messages?

Comment: I would suggest reading the links, then, instead of call setText call addActionListerner